# Interfacing LIVE SPEECH with Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, tkinter, speech-recognition, pocketsphinx

I want to interface pocketsphinx livespeech with Python tkinter GUI in such a way that GUI is visible on frontend and Livespeech works on Back-end.But when i merge tkinter code with livespeech code; livespeech code always runs first and GUI not shows till i stop the code;so i won't be able to perform my required task..,

```
    #*********************************** IMPORTING MODULES*****************
import tkinter
from tkinter import*
import tkinter.messagebox
import sqlite3
import os
from pocketsphinx import LiveSpeech, get_model_path


conn = sqlite3.connect('portal.db')
c = conn.cursor()

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Smart Notice Board")

top = Canvas(window,width=400,height=200)
top.pack(fill=X)

def portal():
    print("2")

button_5 = Button(text='PORTAL SYSTEM', height = 2, width=17, activebackground = '#33B5e5', bg = 'brown', fg = 'white',command  = portal )
top.create_window(80,80, anchor='nw', window = button_5) 

#****************  TEXT TO SPEECH CODE***************

model_path = get_model_path()

speech = LiveSpeech(
    verbose=False,
    sampling_rate=16000,
    buffer_size=2048,
    no_search=False,
    full_utt=False,
    hmm=os.path.join(model_path, 'en-us'),
    lm=os.path.join(model_path, '8582.lm'),
    dic=os.path.join(model_path, '8582.dict')
)

for phrase in speech:
    print(phrase)
    a=str(phrase)
    if a == "HOME":
        print('ok')
        portal()
        print('1')
```

**results are attached below**; 
Only live speech runs

[image]

GUI opens when code exit

[image]

[image: After adding Multiprocessing]

Comment: Time to learn about https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: i have acted upon your advice;divide both codes in function and includes\ multiprocessing in the code but only difference in the result is that NOW it only opens livespeech (fun2 in code) and doesnot open tkinter GUI(fun) whereas previously it open GUI when code stops but now it won't do that

Comment: GUI should be the main thread.

Comment: Tried GUI as main thread too and call livespeech after that, still GUI opens when i exit the code

Comment: You can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47670677/python-tkinter-multiprocessing-progress for the proper implementation with pipes between thread and main loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Tkinter multiprocessing progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47670677/python-tkinter-multiprocessing-progress)